# Hadoop MapReduce - Join of two files and Computation on grouped values

Tags: java, hadoop, join, mapreduce, multiple-input

I am fairly new to Hadoop and MapReduce programming. I want to know whether it is possible to group by another value (not key) after joining of two files.

I have two files which have following data

File1

```
name    marks
A       Male
B       Male
C       Female
```

File2

```
name    marks
A       25
B       28
A       30
C       22
```

Now is there any method to find the percentage of marks for each gender. I am trying to get the following as output

```
Male    percentage_of_marks_of_male_students
Female  percentage_of_marks_of_female_students
```

Is there anyway to do this in a single job. I've tried using two jobs for this, but couldn't find any headway.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Edit:

After joining the files I get something like this

```
{name1 - ["gender","marks1","marks2",...]}
{name2 - ["gender","marks1","marks2",...]}
{name3 - ["gender","marks1","marks2",...]}
...
```

I'm currently stuck at finding sum of marks of male and females separately in the reducer phase

Edit:

I have solved the problem. I used two jobs. First job joins two files, gives output as

```
[gender, the sum of marks of each student]
```

I sent the output file as input to second job which gives percentage of marks by gender.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the result of joining the two files would look like, since you say that you want to make this job _after_ the join has been made?

Comment: After joining I'm expecting to get in this format 
{name1 - ["gender","marks1","marks2",...]}
{name2 - ["gender","marks1","marks2",...]}
{name3 - ["gender","marks1","marks2",...]}
....

Comment: What do you mean by _percentage_ of marks? Like the sum of them, or the sum of them by the total number of marks?

Comment: I meant it as sum of them by total marks.

I have solved the problem. I used a counter to sum up the total marks and in the second job I found the percentage. Thank you for taking time to help me.